# AjaxFormLoop not populating values for the newly created form elements after submission

Tags: tapestry

Can someone please point out when/where in the code during the form submission, ajaxformloop copies the newly added row results
I'm referring to the following example code - 
http://jumpstart.doublenegative.com.au/jumpstart/examples/ajax/formloop1

I've a similar code, following is my ValueEncoder

```
@Log
public ValueEncoder<Promotion> getPromotionEncoder() {

    return new ValueEncoder<Promotion>() {

        @Log
        public String toClient(Promotion promo) {
            log.debug("toClient id="+promo.getId());
            if (promo.getId() == 0)
            {
                return NEW_PROMOTION;
            }
            return new Long(promo.getId()).toString();
        }
        @Log
        public Promotion toValue(String id) {

            log.debug("toValue id="+id);
            Promotion promotion = null;

            if (id.equals(NEW_PROMOTION))
            {
                promotion = new Promotion();
                newPromotions.add(promotion);
            }
            else 
            {
                promotion = crudService.findUniqueWithNamedQuery(Promotion.BY_ID,
                                    QueryParameters.with("id", new Long(id).longValue()).parameters());
            }
            return promotion == null? new Promotion(): promotion;
        }
    };
}
```

When `onSuccess()` method is called after the form submission, I can't access the values of the newly created rows which I store in `newPromotions` in the `toValue()` method above.

Appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 0):

Your comparison in toClient is wrong:

```
if (promo.getId() == 0){ return NEW_PROMOTION; }
```

when you instantiate a new Promotion, it's ID is most likely not zero, but NULL.
The Jumpstart ValueEncoder is doing it like this:

```
return id == null ? NEW_PERSON : id.toString();
```

Therefore your toValue method fails too :)